# commandlink, outputlink , commanbutton, rich:menuItem to use

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I have faced one difficulty in *JSF 2* based application.
I wanted to use navigation from one view to another along with a value passing through **rich:menuItem**,

1. So I tried to use **h:outputLink** and it navigates as well, but is not passing the value which i want to pass before it navigates to display the required resultset.
2. The same for **a4j:commandLink**.
3. then I used **a4J:commandButton** itself to perform this by using action and actionListener.
   Here *Action* will navigate to next view and *Listener* will pass the value to the required class and "listener will be called before action". The code for doing this is....

   ```
   <rich:menuItem ajaxSingle="true">
        <a4j:commandButton value="Show Particulars" action="details" event="onclick" actionListener="#{payeeParticularsController.showParticulars}"/>
   </rich:menuItem>
   ```

but this button looks really awkward for use.
So can anybody help me to do this by either using outputLink, commandLink, rich:menuItem (would be best to do), or any other well user friendly way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way, if it helps

```
<h:commandLink id="btn" value="Show Particulars" action="{payeeParticularsController.showParticulars}">
     <f:param name="menuItem" value="#{}" />
 </h:commandLink>
```

Where the command link takes the menu item as a parameter

UPDATE:
 In the bean

```
public String showParticulars(){
   // get the f:parama value using facesContect
   // use it as required
   ...
   return "\newView.xhtml";
}
```

UPDATE 2:

If the above did not work try it this way

```
 <rich:menuItem submitMode="ajax" value="Show Particulars" action="#{Bean.showParticulars}" >
 </rich:menuItem>
```

and the Bean would be

```
public String showParticulars() 
{
      ..
return "/logout.xhtml";
}
```

where the submitMode="ajax" will help u make it work as commandLink and the Bean's show particulars() will navigate to another view

Comment: I'll try what u r telling, but what param does here??

Comment: You wanted to use navigation from one view to another along with a value passing through rich:menuItem..correct..??? My answer was to use a `<h:commandLink>` where its action method takes the menuItem (which u wanted again as `f:param`, To navigate to another view on its action, we must return the the respective page, which redirects to a new page/view

Comment: Its not working dude I tried with both returning the view and the rules outcome.

Comment: btw what needs to put in value="#{}"

Comment: I am having my beaqn in requestScoped so shall i chage it to viewscoped.

Comment: if u have defined the menuItem in the bean then u've to put value=#{bean.menuItem}, also try changing it to viewScope or session scope

Comment: actually I was asking how can i put commandLink in rich:menuItem under rich:contextMenu.....like the one I displayed in my original question, just in place of a4j:commandButton put h:commandLink something like that.....

Comment: the only thing that i did not tried earlier and i tried now and have made the desirable output is **submitMode="ajax"**. That's the only thing I wanted. Thanks once again...

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It's working for me.

```
<rich:menuItem submitMode="none">
   <h:commandLink value="Show Particulars" action="details" actionListener="#{payeeParticularsController.showParticulars}"/>
</rich:menuItem>
```

or if you have ajax

```
<rich:menuItem submitMode="none">
   <a4j:commandLink value="Show Particulars" reRender="body" action="details" actionListener="#{payeeParticularsController.showParticulars}"/>
</rich:menuItem>
```

And, I would sugges to use attribute **immediate="true"** in menues.

Reference : http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_menuItem.html